# How do I limit the number of files printed by ls?

Tags: command-line, ls, limit

Is there a way to limit the quantity of listed files on a `ls` command?

I've seen:

```
ls | head -4
```

but to get `head` or `tail` to be executed I need to wait for `ls` to finish execution,
and with directories with an enourmous quantity of files that can take considerable time.

I wish to execute a `ls` command that limits without using that `head` command.

Answer (score 221):

Have you tried

```
ls -U | head -4
```

This should skip the sorting, which is probably why `ls` is taking so long.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193/quick-ls-command

Comment: "ls -U" still reads the entire directory before print... I think that I'll write a small script to limit the files, but that question link is good reading material. Thanks niko.

Comment: @AndreDurao, GNU `ls -U` does not necessarily read the entire directory before printing. Try `strace -e getdents,write ls -U > /dev/null` in a large directory for instance.

Comment: Just a note: if you want to execute strace on OSX look for dtrace, the strace command is a Linux utility

Answer (score 21):

If your version of `ls` has a way not to sort files, such as [`-U` for GNU ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21471/how-to-limit-ls-files/21472#21472), use it. With no option, `ls` will first read all the files, then sort the names, then start printing.

Another possibility is to run `find`, which prints names as it finds them.

```
find . -name . -o -prune | head
```

(note that since `head` is working on *lines*, that assumes file names don't contain newline characters).

Comment: Note that in the case of GNU `find` (as opposed to busybox or heirloom `find` or GNU `ls -U`), it seems it reads the whole directory before starting to print.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you are in need of a tool other than `ls`?

For example, Randal Schwartz has a blog entry about [using `perl` on large directories](http://blogs.perl.org/users/randal_l_schwartz/2011/03/perl-to-the-rescue-case-study-of-deleting-a-large-directory.html) that may contain some hints on building something that meets your needs.

In the blog posting Randal explains that both `ls` and `find` attempt to read in all directory entries before printing any, while the `perl` solution he proposes does not.

Comment: I also thought that could be the best option, because both ls and find read the entire directory before printing. I was planning to write a ruby script to do that instead of pearl, thanks for that AFresh1!

Comment: @AndreDurao, `perl` probably uses `readdir(3)` like `ls` or `find`. `readdir(3)` on current versions of GNU/Linux at least does call the `getdents()` system call with a large _count_ (that actually does generally optimise performances by reducing the number of system calls being made). But in your case, if you want fewer files, it looks like you'd have to bypass `readdir` and use BSDs `getdirentries(3)` or the `getdents(2)` system call instead.

Answer (score 4):

If performance is not the concern (as in the question that was closed as a duplicate of this one), and you want to list the first n files (as opposed to the first n lines of the output of `ls`) in the list of non-hidden files sorted by filename, with `zsh`, you can use:

```
ls -ld -- *([1,4])
```

to list the first 4 files. `zsh` will still read the full content of the directory though, even if you tell it not to sort with `*(oN[1,4])` (note that `ls` *also* sorts that list).

Answer (score 3):

On an unrelated note (because this question comes up when you google "linux tree limit number of files as output"), you can use `tree --filelimit=10` (descend directories where only 10 or less files are present). It nicely gives you the output as follows

```bsh
tree --filelimit=10
```

It lists directory structure and contents. Very helpful when exploring large datasets (when you are first interested in knowing the structure/hierarchy).

```
.
├── gps
│   ├── gps.csv
│   └── ins.csv
├── mono_rear [2217 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
├── mono_rear.timestamps
├── stereo
│   └── centre [3164 entries exceeds filelimit, not opening dir]
└── stereo.timestamps
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *less* is better suited for your needs?

```
 ls /usr/bin | less
```

For me, it works instantaneously on a 5 years old laptop with classic HDD, but head is equally fast.

You can terminate `less` prematurely with <kbd>q</kbd>.

I guess your assumption about the source of the 1s delay is wrong, but maybe depends on your Unix-flavour or your shell, less or head command.

On Linux, with GNU-ls,

```
 ls -R /usr | less
```

starts outputting immediately for me, while the whole output is running und running - so it is definitively not finished, before less starts. You might check, if you have a constant delay of 1s or maybe more, depending on the output or not.

I guess your 1s delay has a different reason, maybe the HDD is going to sleep and needs a wakeup?

Do you have such a delay for very few files too?

Comment: Thanks but I wasn't looking for something like that. Just like head the less is executed with the result of the entire `ls` result. I was looking for a way to ls itself to limit the results qty.

Comment: @AndreDurao: Moved my comments into the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
ls -lrth | tail

ls -lrth | tail -n 10

ls -lrth | grep *.gz | tail
```

Comment: I'm Sorry Abhishek, but the point of this question is to avail `ls` command on bash. Piped commands like `grep`, `head`, `tail` or others are executed after the `ls`

Answer (score -1):

```
$ cut -f 1,n filename
```

will do the task of fetching first `n` files.
`n` is number of files you want to extract.
so complete code will be:

```
$ ls|cut -f 1,n file
```

Comment: The `ls | cut -f 1,n file` command you suggested would output the first and nth field on each line of text in `file`, and would completely ignore the output of `ls`. This does not do what the original poster needs.

Comment: Yes you are right .just a correction make it     ls | head -n ...This will surely do the task.